# Firestore local filtering

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has read quota and price for every 100K reads.
I have very simple task to do in relation-based DB, but it looks like overhead for Firestore:

- I have Firestore collection "articles", every article has field "viewed_by_uids" as Array of Firebase user UID's
- I've already read 100K articles(which is short)
- I want to get UNreaded articles for my UID

Do I really need to query this 100K readed articles with paging, for example, of 50 items per page to filter it LOCALLY(send too much data through my weak mobile network) and finally get UNreaded articles to display?

**EDIT: clarifications**
Here is how I'am creating "article" in Android with Kotlin:

```
    data class Article (
val title: String, 
val text: String, 
val ownerUid: String, 
@ServerTimestamp val creationDate: Date? = null)
```

//writing filled article to firestore

```
val article = Article (title = "test title" text = "test text", ownerUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!)

val articleRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(Article.COLLECTION_NAME)
            .document()
.set(article)
            .addOnFailureListener { ...just show error }
            .addOnSuccessListener { ...just show success }
```

Showing list of articles written NOT by me is made by **FirestoreRecyclerAdapter** with options:

```
val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection(Article.COLLECTION_NAME)
            .orderBy("creationDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .limit(ITEMS_PER_QUERY_LIMIT)

FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Task>()
                .setQuery(query, Task::class.java)
                .build()
```

For now I don't really understand how to filter incoming items and show only articles where ownerUid != FirestoreAuth.getInstance().uid!!
I'm just hiding RecyclerView item by item root LayoutParams - crazy! :(
I think I need custom Adapter to **EXCLUDE** my articles DocumentSnapshots?
- In this case it means if I wrote 100K articles already and I need to get them all through network **TO JUST EXCLUDE AND DON'T SHOW ?**

Comment: The question is slightly unclear but I think the answer will depend on how your database is structured and how to try to get to the data. A query is not the same as a read so we would need more information to provide any kind of accurate answer. Perhaps including some code to demonstrate how you are fetching data?

Comment: just updated my question with sample code of using Firestore, please help